# Equivalent for optionsAfterRender on a foreach binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

In Knockout, the "`options`" binding has an optional argument `optionsAfterRender which is used to modify the individual option tags as they are inserted. You can [find more details in the documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

For one of my select lists, I am having to use a `foreach` binding instead, because it requires a two-level binding using `optgroup`.

```
<select  data-bind="foreach: { data: availableData,
                              value: editDataId">
  <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: groupTitle}, foreach: groups">
    <option data-bind="value: id, attr: {title: name }"></option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

However, I would also like to modify these options after binding.

There is an `afterRender` option for `foreach`, but it seems to behave very differently than `optionsAfterRender`. I was able to get it to execute against all the options in the select list as follows:

```
<select  data-bind="foreach: { data: availableData,
                              value: editDataId,
                              afterRender: doStuff">
  <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: groupTitle}, foreach: groups">
    <option data-bind="value: id, attr: {title: name }"></option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

And then in the viewmodel

```
doStuff(elements, data): void {
    for (let entry of elements[1].querySelectorAll("option")) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(entry, {disable: true }, entry);
    }
}
```

(I don't really want to disable them all - it's just a simple test) - but this lead to the curious result of the entire select list not rendering at all. On inspection the nodes are still there - in the HTML and they can be traveresed and logged - but they're not appearing on the page.

This isn't because they're disabled. Something in the binding is causing the whole thing to go screwy. Is there a way I can mimic the operation of `optionsAfterRender` on this `foreach` binding?

Comment: Useless to ask, but I'd appreciate knowing why someone thought this merited a downvote? I thought I'd made a clear problem statement, and shown what I'd attempted so far.

Comment: Your data binding has an unclosed curly-brace. Is that just a typo in the sample or does that exist in your actual code?

Comment: @JasonSpake It's a typo. In the actual code I'm using a bootstrap select-picker and it looks like that's the real source of the problem, as your sample neatly demonstrates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from fixing the un-closed foreach binding typo I also found I needed to change the option's "title" binding to "label" to get the individual option text to show up. Other than that your code seems to function as expected.

```js
function viewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.editDataId = 1;
  self.availableData = [
    { groupTitle: 'group1', groups: [ {id: 1, name: 'item1'}, {id: 2, name: 'item2'} ] } ,
    { groupTitle: 'group2', groups: [ {id: 3, name: 'item3'}, {id: 4, name: 'item4'} ] } 
  ];
 
  self.doStuff = function(elements, data) {
    for (let entry of elements[1].querySelectorAll("option")) {
      ko.applyBindingsToNode(entry, { disable: true }, entry);
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select  data-bind="foreach: { data: availableData,
                              value: editDataId,
                              afterRender: doStuff }">
  <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: groupTitle}, foreach: groups">
    <option data-bind="value: id, attr: {label: name}"></option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```